# Reading data as a stream using Elixir and Hackney

Tags: elixir

I'm playing with the [hackney](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney) and I'm trying to read the body of a request as a stream using the instructions from [here](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney#read-the-body).
Since the code there is written in Erlang I had to adapt it to work in Elixir:

```
  def read_body(max_length, client, acc) when max_length > byte_size(acc) do
    case :hackney.stream_body(client) do
      {:ok, data} -> read_body(max_length, client, acc <> data)
      :done -> {:ok, acc}
      {:error, reason} -> {:error, reason}
    end
  end

  def read_body(max_length, client, acc) do
    acc
  end
```

And I run it using:

```
acc = HackneyTutorial.read_body(20, client, "")                     
# I have my own methods for retrieving the client
```

The problem is that I would expect to read only the first 20 bytes of data from the body using the code above however the `acc` variable gets the entire body, it either doesn't take into account the guard `when max_length > byte_size(acc)`, or it simply reads all the body on the first  call to `:hackney.stream_body/1` .

What do you think might fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One of two things is happening with your `read_body/3` function:

1. As you mentioned, the entire body is being returned at once from the `:hackney.stream_body/1` call which happens to be larger than `max_length`, which then causes the second definition of `read_body/3` to be called.
2. Portions of the body are being returned as `read_body/3` executes recursively until the size of `acc` is no longer smaller than `max_length`, which then causes the second definition of `read_body/3` to be called (same result as 1).

Neither the `:hackney.stream_body/1` function nor your `read_body/3` guard will *actually* limit the size of the returned body based on `max_length`.  In both cases where `acc` is larger than the specified `max_length`, the `:done` case (or the `{:error, reason}` case) will never match.

In order to limit the size of the returned body, one solution would be to add two additional guards to your `case` expression and remove your secondary definition of `read_body/3` without the guard:

```erlang
def read_body(max_length, ref, acc) do
  case :hackney.stream_body(ref) do
    {:ok, _} when byte_size(acc) > max_length ->
      read_body(max_length, ref, acc)
    {:ok, data} when (byte_size(data) + byte_size(acc)) > max_length ->
      read_body(max_length, ref, acc <> String.slice(data, 0, max_length - byte_size(acc)))
    {:ok, data} ->
      read_body(max_length, ref, acc <> data)
    :done ->
      {:ok, acc}
    {:error, reason} ->
      {:error, reason}
  end
end
```

Another solution might be to subtract the size of the returned data from `max_length` until reaching `0`, then ignore the rest of the data:

```erlang
def read_body(0, ref, acc) do
  case :hackney.stream_body(ref) do
    {:ok, _} ->
      read_body(0, ref, acc)
    :done ->
      {:ok, acc}
    {:error, reason} ->
      {:error, reason}
  end
end
def read_body(max_length, ref, acc) do
  case :hackney.stream_body(ref) do
    {:ok, << data :: binary-size(max_length), _ :: binary >>} ->
      read_body(0, ref, acc <> data)
    {:ok, data} ->
      read_body(max_length - byte_size(data), ref, acc <> data)
    :done ->
      {:ok, acc}
    {:error, reason} ->
      {:error, reason}
  end
end
```

Both solutions have the same result, but show a couple of different approaches for solving the same issue.